# How can I print the integer part of a floating point number with 2 digits using leading zeros in Rust?

Tags: rust, format, number-formatting, percentage

How do I format `5.0` into `05.0%`? Using `{:02.2}` does not seem to work; it does the same as `{.2}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#width

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:04.1}%", 5.0);
}
```

prints

`05.0%`

which is padded to a length of 4 characters including the decimal point. Your example would be padded to length 2, but already has length 3, thus nothing changes.

Comment: This requires limiting how many decimal points will be printed which (a) isn't explicitly stated in the answer (b) isn't explicitly indicated as something that the OP wanted.